# R nested functions

Tags: r, nested-function

I have to calculate the number of missing values per observation in a data set. As there are several variables across multiple time periods, I thought it best to try a function to keep my syntax clean. The first part of looking up the number of missing values works fine:

```
data$NMISS <- data %>% 
  select('x1':'x4') %>%  
  apply(1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

But when I try turn it into a function I get "Error in select():! NA/NaN argument"

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA, 1, 5, 1),   
                   x2 = c(7, 1, 1, 5),
                   x3 = c(9, NA, 4, 9),
                   x4 = c(3, 4, 1, 2))

NMISSfunc <- function (dataFrame,variables) {
  
  dataFrame %>% select(variables) %>% 
    apply(1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
  
}

data$NMISS2 <- NMISSfunc(data,'x1':'x4')
```

I think it doesn't like the `:` in the range as it will accept `c('x1','x2','x3','x4')` instead of `'x1':'x4'`

Some of the ranges are over twenty columns so listing them doesn't really provide a solution to keep the syntax neat.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that you can't use `"x4":"x4"`, as this isn't valid use of the `:` operator in this context. To get this to work in a tidyverse-style, your `variables` variable needs to be selectively unquoted inside `select`. Fortunately, the tidyverse has the curly-curly notation `{{variables}}` for handling exactly this situation:

```r
NMISSfunc <- function (dataFrame, variables) {
  
  dataFrame %>% 
    select({{variables}}) %>% 
    apply(1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
}
```

Now we can use `x1:x4` (without quotes) and the function works as expected:

```r
NMISSfunc(data, x1:x4)
#> [1] 1 1 0 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @user2554330 fair point. Inexact terminology. I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply,

```
data %>% 
 mutate(NMISS = rowSums(is.na(select(., x1:x4))))

  x1 x2 x3 x4 NMISS
1 NA  7  9  3     1
2  1  1 NA  4     1
3  5  1  4  1     0
4  1  5  9  2     0
```